Why does my Asus Vivobook Pro 15 suddenly shutdown while I am working?
I have Asus Vivobook Pro 15 M3500QC. Recently for few days my laptop shutsdown loosing all my work from nowhere. What can be the issue? Is it the motherboard Issue or Windows? I recently replaced my speakers and left side fan as my laptop is under warranty.
Any help will be greatful.
Here are some specs:
Processor
Model: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics
Cores: 12
Speed: 4.2 GHz
Stepping: 0
Family: 19
Model Number: 50
CPU ID: 178BFBFF00A50F00
Memory (RAM)
Total: 16 GB
Graphics
AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics

Chipset: AMD Radeon(TM) Graphics
Manufacturer: ATI
Hardware T&L: Yes
Total Memory: 9.0 GB
Dedicated Memory: 1.0 GB
Driver Version: 30.0.13044.14002
Vertex Shader Version: 6.0
Pixel Shader Version: 6.0
Plug and Play ID: VEN_1002&DEV_1638&SUBSYS_186C1043&REV_C6
Device ID: 1638
Vendor ID: 1002
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU

Chipset: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3050 Laptop GPU
Manufacturer: Nvidia
Hardware T&L: Yes
Total Memory: 12 GB
Dedicated Memory: 4.0 GB
Driver Version: 32.0.15.6614
Vertex Shader Version: 6.0
Pixel Shader Version: 6.0
Plug and Play ID: VEN_10DE&DEV_25A2&SUBSYS_186C1043&REV_A1
Device ID: 25A2
Vendor ID: 10DE
Operating System
OS: Windows 11
Version: 10.0.26100
Architecture: 64-bit
Locale: 4009
BIOS
Version: M3500QC.316
Manufacturer: American Megatrends International, LLC


We cannot say. Is it giving a BSOD? What does the battery say before it dies? Do you get warnings or messages when you power it back on? Will it power back on right away, or do you have to do something before it'll start again? You need to give us more information, any information you have collected regarding the issue, and add it to the main question.

What does the Event Log show? https://www.windowscentral.com/how-find-reason-pc-shutdown-no-reason-windows-10 . If there is no entry, then likely there is a hardware issue -- could be as simple as a loose connector, or a soldered connection to the PCB that can be easily reflowed... or it could be a major issue, making it unfeasible to repair.
